# How to reduce the number of times a heavy objects.all query runs on foriegn key field in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, query-cache

I found that the MySQL DB was becoming unresponsive each time I would load the admin page for a model. I investigated and found that the query `Model.objects.all()` was running innumerable times, I thought there was some problem because of which django caching is not working, but i verified the caching part through running the query on django shell.I am still lost, I have code similar to this :

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=true)

class Accessories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, db_index=true)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

its is very straightforward and I am still not able to understand what is going on ?

Comment: Are you running with `debug = True` in your settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have overridden `__str__` method to have all the related model objects printed somewhere like `self.cars.all()` , in that case you need to use the prefetch_reload mechanism like this :

```
Accessories.objects.all().prefetch_related('cars')
```

This will reduce the workload as it will prefetch the cars for a given accessory from a pre-populated queryset instead of going to the MySQL DB each time.

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for :), completely nails it, this is what my `__str__` function

`def __str__(self):
        
return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, ", ".join([car.name for car in self.cars.all()]))`